# integral calculus velocity of a body

Tags: calculus

Could anyone help me with i) please? And check my answer for the other 2 questions. Struggling with this .

[image]

ii)
$$ v = u + at $$
$$ 5 = 2 + a x 60$$
$$a = \frac{5-2}{60} = \frac{1}{20} m/s^2$$
$$v^2 = u^2 + 2as$$
$$5^2 = 2^2 + 2 . \frac{1}{20} . s$$
$$ s = \frac{20(25-4)}{2} = 210m$$

iii)
$$v = u + at = 2 + \frac{1}{20} . 120 = 8m/s$$
$$v^2 = u^2 + 2as$$
$$8^2 = 2^2 + 2 x {1}{20} . s$$
$$s = \frac{20(64-4)}{2} = 600m$$

Distance traveled after 2 minutes 600m

If the acceleration has stopped after 1 minute.
The distance covered in the second minute = vt = 5 × 60 = 300 m.
The distance travelled in 2  minutes = 210 + 300 = 510 m.

Comment: all the kinematics equations you used, like $v=u+at$, $v^2 = u^2 + 2as$ are only true if the acceleration $a$ is constant. In your current question, $a$ is not constant ($a$ actually changes with time) so your entire method is wrong. Also, there is no way (that I see) for you to solve parts (ii) and (iii) without (i). To do part (i), you need to use the fact that position $s$ is the integral of velocity: $s = \int v(t) \, dt $. For the subsequent parts, you need to know the relationship between distance and position

Comment: You should show your problem as text in your question rather than as a graphic. That makes it possible for us to copy-and-paste into our editors. It also makes it much easier for others to search for your question and the resulting answers, so this helps others in the future.